# Vue.js inline edit component is sorted by lodash before save

Tags: arrays, vue.js, lodash

I have a Vue.js component that displays some items. When the "Edit" button is pressed an inline editor is displayed. I also use lodash to sort the items by name. The problem is that after every keyup lodash sorts the array immediately producing a weird position change. The sort logic is in a computed method.

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
     <single-item v-for="item in orderedItems" :item="item" :key="item.id"></single-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

[...]

```
computed: {
  orderedItems: function() {
    return _.sortBy(this.items, 'name')
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/147167/)

As you can see upon initialisation lodash sorts the items by name producing a 2,1,3 order. But when the user edits the 'aaa' value to something like 'daaa' this weird position change takes place. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess here: computed is called each time vue.js detects a change in the data being watched. Try binding a method to an event handler, maybe when saving the text value

Comment: This happens because you are editing the model in the child and the computed is doing what computed properties do; updating when the model changes. Instead, you should emit the change from the child when the editing is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to avoid the direct mutation of the item inside the child component. Instead just notify the parent once the "Save" button was pressed that data actually changed.
I have updated your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/uqbvLy4x/

The gist of it:

Setup a watcher for changes to the item so that you clone it for *local* changes inside the child component:

```
  watch: {
    item: {
       handler: function (item) {
            this.mutableItem = _.clone(item)
       },
       immediate: true
    }
  }
```

Let the parent know that an item was updated in the child component inside the save function:

```
save: function(item) {
    this.editMode = false     
    this.$emit('update:item', this.mutableItem)
}
```

Capture and process the information about a changed item inside the parent:

```
<single-item v-for="item in orderedItems" :item="item" :key="item.id"
       @update:item="onItemUpdated"></single-item>

   onItemUpdated: function (mutableItem) {
     console.log(mutableItem)
     const itemIndex = _.findIndex(this.items, item => {
       return item.id === mutableItem.id
      })
      this.items.splice(itemIndex, 1, mutableItem)
   }
```

I am sure that there are other and potentially better solutions to this, but this was how i handled this.

**EDIT:** To be more specific about the watcher: You only need the watcher and clone if you pass down a complete object! This is because you basically are getting a reference to the original object. This is also stated in the documenation:

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so
> if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself
> inside the child component will affect parent state.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow